# Constructor injection using Spring annotation @Autowired does not work

Tags: spring, annotations, default-constructor, constructor-injection

I have created 2 simple classes. Constructor of one class is annotated as @Autowired. It accepts the object of another class. But this code fails.

Classes :-
1) SimpleBean.java

```
@Configuration
public class SimpleBean {
  InnerBean prop1;

  public InnerBean getProp1() {
    return prop1;
  }

  public void setProp1( InnerBean prop1) {
    System.out.println("inside setProp1 input inner's property is "
        + prop1.getSimpleProp1());
    this.prop1 = prop1;
  }

  @Autowired(required=true)
  public SimpleBean(InnerBean prop1) {
    super();
    System.out.println("inside SimpleBean constructor inner's property is "
        + prop1.getSimpleProp1());
    this.prop1 = prop1;
  }
}
```

2) Inner.java

```
@Configuration
public class InnerBean {
  String simpleProp1;

  public String getSimpleProp1() {
    return simpleProp1;
  }

  public void setSimpleProp1(String simpleProp1) {
    this.simpleProp1 = simpleProp1;
  }

}
```

When I try to load ApplicationConext

```
ApplicationContext acnxt = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext("com.domain");
```

It gives following error :-

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:         Error creating bean with name 'simpleBean' defined in file [C:\Users\owner\Documents\Java Project\MyWorkSpace\springMVCSecond\WebContent\WEB-INF\classes\com\domain\SimpleBean.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.domain.SimpleBean$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$4bc418be]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.domain.SimpleBean$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$4bc418be.<init>()
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:965)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:911)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:192)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:75)
at com.test.SpringAnnotationTest.main(SpringAnnotationTest.java:12)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.domain.SimpleBean$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$4bc418be]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.domain.SimpleBean$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$4bc418be.<init>()
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:70)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:958)
... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.domain.SimpleBean$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$4bc418be.<init>()
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:65)
... 13 more
```

If I introduce no-arg constructor in SimpleBean class. It does not give error. 
But this does not give me pre-poulated object of SimpleBean ( as in XML configuration using < constructor-arg > ).
So when using annotation, is it mandatory to have no-arg constructor ?
What is the appropriate way out ?

Comment: Are you trying to call like `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext("com.domain")` Package? Please put your complete code.

Comment: @RaviParekh yes, these classes are in com.domain package. And I am trying to call ApplicationContext acnxt = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext("com.domain");  It was already mentioned.

Answer (score 21):

From the javadoc of `@Configuration`:

```
 Configuration is meta-annotated as a {@link Component}, therefore Configuration
 classes are candidates for component-scanning and may also take advantage of
 {@link Autowired} at the field and method but not at the constructor level.
```

So you'll have to find some other way to do it, unfortunately.

Answer (score 7):

I believe you are mixing up the `@Configuration` and `@Component` annotation.  As per the [spring docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java), [`@Configuration`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html) is used to create beans using Java code (any methods annotated with `@Bean` create a bean, whereas classes annotated with [`@Component`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Component.html) are automatically created..

I hope the following illustrates this:

InnerBean.java:

```
// this bean will be created by Config
public class InnerBean {
  String simpleProp1;

  public String getSimpleProp1() {
    return simpleProp1;
  }

  public void setSimpleProp1(String simpleProp1) {
    this.simpleProp1 = simpleProp1;
  }
}
```

SimpleBean.java:

```
// This bean will be created because of the @Component annotation, 
// using the constructor with the inner bean autowired in
@Component
public class SimpleBean {
  InnerBean prop1;

  public InnerBean getProp1() {
    return prop1;
  }

  @Autowired(required = true)
  public SimpleBean(InnerBean prop1) {
    this.prop1 = prop1;
  }
}
```

OuterBean.java

```
// this bean will be created by Config and have the SimpleBean autowired.
public class OuterBean {
  SimpleBean simpleBean;

  @Autowired
  public void setSimpleBean(SimpleBean simpleBean) {
    this.simpleBean = simpleBean;
  }

  public SimpleBean getSimpleBean() {
    return simpleBean;
  }
}
```

Config.java

```
// this class will create other beans
@Configuration
public class Config {
  @Bean
  public OuterBean outerBean() {
    return new OuterBean();
  }

  @Bean
  public InnerBean innerBean() {
    InnerBean innerBean = new InnerBean();
    innerBean.setSimpleProp1("test123");
    return innerBean;
  }
}
```

Main.java:

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext("com.acme");
    OuterBean outerBean = ctx.getBean("outerBean", OuterBean.class);
    System.out.println(outerBean.getSimpleBean().getProp1().getSimpleProp1());
  }
}
```

The main class uses the [`AnnotationConfigApplicationContext`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.html) to scan for both `@Configuration` and `@Component` annotations and create the beans accordingly.

Comment: In my code, I changed annotation from @ Configuration to @ Component in both the classes SimpleBean and InnerBean. Still I am getting same error. It is still complaining "No default constructor found".

Comment: I've tested the example code I provided with Spring 3.0.6 and it prints "test123".  Which version of spring are you using?  You may want to show more of your configuration because the class name `com.domain.SimpleBean$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$4bc418be.<init>()` suggests that there are further proxies involved.

Comment: I tested it using spring 3.0.6 jars only. When I marked classes with @ component instead of @ configuration; it had similar error. Only CGLIB part was not involved.

Comment: can you check by try running my code. Classes with @ Configuration  and once with @ Component.

Comment: I've run your code and it prints: `inside SimpleBean constructor inner's property is null` (using `@Component`)